# Deleted table row reappears after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, rows

I have a simply html table, and script that deletes a row whenever delete is clicked, however as soon as I refresh the page the deleted row re-appears again. How can I actually delete the row in the file? Do I need to use php?

Html:

```
<table id="row"> 
  <tr>
    <td><a href=''>row1</a></td>
    <td><a  class='delete' href=''>Delete</a></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href=''>row2</a></td>
    <td><a  class='delete' href=''>Delete</a></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href=''>row3</a></td>
    <td><a  class='delete' href=''>Delete</a></td>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

Script:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#row .delete").on("click",function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");
        tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
            tr.remove().clone();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: When you refresh the page you're starting again. You're just deleting from the DOM, and can't change the html file itself from JavaScript.

Comment: You probably need to delete from the database, or if you don't have a database you are serving static html in your file and not modifying the contents of the file on the server. The javascript you posted just removes it from the users display after run time execution. It doesn't actually modify the contents of any files or databases where information is stored.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with php?

Comment: You can do anything with PHP. It runs on the server, and you can communicate with it via Ajax for eg. But if you're asking these types of questions really you need to start with reading a book or three, covering basic website building using PHP, jQuery, and probably MySQL (because you're talking about a dynamic site, even if it's a single seemingly trivial page).

Comment: This looks like another question asked earlier? Take a look at my answer and see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821704/php-unlink-when-clicking/26822061#26822061

Comment: @LarryLane That question was about deleting a file. This is about changing HTML inside a web page.

Answer (score 0):

If this table is being created on a static HTML page then i dont know ways to delete the row and keep-ing it deleted after refresh (probably you should take a look at the usage of local objects storage).

If this table is being generated using data taken from e given database (data parsed using php) and rendered on page using html/css, then Yes, you should use PHP to delete the row even after the page refreshes.

The jquery code that you posted is only valid only until you reload the page, so when you reload page everything goes back to initial state since when you clicked that X button (delete button), you didnt actualy deleted anything ... you just made a row of the table hidden.